# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}dx$ by complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

When calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx（0<a<1）$, one way is to draw the path *C1* like the first picture. Then we have

$\int_{C1}\frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z}dz=\int_r^R\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx+\int_R^r\frac{x^{a-1}e^{i2\pi(a-1)}}{1+x}dx+\int_{|z|=R}+\int_{|z|=r}=Res(-1)$.

Let $R\to\infty$  and $r\to0$, the first and second term on the right side will become:
$[1-e^{2i\pi(a-1)}]\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx$
Then the rest of the problem will be easy.

I want to use similar method to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}dx$  so I draw the path *C2* like the second picture and have this equation.

$\int_{C2}\frac{z^{a-1}}{1-z}dz=\int_{CA}+\int_{BD}+\int_{|z|=R}+\int_{|z|=r}=Res(1)$

But I am confused when intergrating the function on *CA* and *BD*.
When integrating on CA, I let $z=xe^{i\pi}=-x$ so $z=e^{logx+i\pi}$ and $dz=-dx$, then

$\int_{CA}\frac{z^{a-1}}{1-z}dz=\int_{R}^{r}\frac{e^{(a-1)(logx+i\pi)}}{1+x}(-dx)$

Similarly, on BD, let $z=xe^{-i\pi}=-x$ ,then

$\int_{BD}\frac{z^{a-1}}{1-z}dz=\int_{r}^{R}\frac{e^{(a-1)(logx-i\pi)}}{1+x}(-dx)$

and the terms about $1-x$ disappeared. It seems like I'm still solving $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx$.

Did I choose the wrong path or have other mistakes? If so, how to draw the suitable and correct path?

[image][image]

Comment: You may use the first contour (as for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx$), but should add (just to make the contour closed and switching from principal value integral to the integral along a closed contour) two half-circles (both in clockwise direction) around $x=1$ - on both side of the cut (the cut is is from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$). Integral along the closed contour is zero (no poles inside), but these additional integrals around $x=1$ will contribute. As for your second contour - it does not imply the initial integral (from zero to $\infty$) as a part of your contour integration.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thank you for your answer : )