Integration $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x} dx$.
I tried to compute the following integral:
$$
\mbox{For}\quad 0 < a < 1,\qquad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a - 1}}{1 - x}{\rm d}x
$$
$$
\mbox{We know that}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a - 1}}{1 - x}{\rm d}x =
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a - 1}}{1 - x}{\rm d}x +
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a - 1}}{1 - x}{\rm d}x
$$
My strategy is to use the relation between Beta function and Gamma function.

But, I can't write
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{a - 1}}{1 - x} {\rm d}x$ as forms of Beta functions:
$$
\operatorname{B}\left(c,d\right) =
\int_{0}^{1}x^{c - 1}\left(1 - x\right)^{d - 1}{\rm d}x
$$
for $\Re\left(c\right)>0,\ \Re\left(d\right) > 0$, since the condition $\Re\left(d\right) > 0$.

Is there any other method to approch this problem ?. Please help me to solve it. Thank you !.

Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084191/42969

For $0<\Re a<1$, interpreted in the Cauchy principal value sense, the integral
\begin{align*}
\text{v.p.}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}dx}{1-x}
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\underbrace{\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{x^{a-1}dx}{1-x}}_{x=t}+\underbrace{\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}dx}{1-x}}_{x=t^{-1}}\right)
\\&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{t^{a-1}\,dt}{1-t}-\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{t^{-a}\,dt}{1-t}\right)-\underbrace{\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{(1+\epsilon)^{-1}}\frac{t^{-a}\,dt}{1-t}}_{=\ 0}
\\&=\int_0^1\frac{t^{a-1}-t^{-a}}{1-t}\,dt=\psi(1-a)-\psi(a)=\color{blue}{\pi\cot\pi a}
\end{align*}
can indeed be computed the gamma/beta way (the last integral is a particular case of the one here, and the last equality is essentially the reflection formula for the digamma function).
